# Build Qt 5.15.2 by Conan and without OpenSSL

Tags: qt, openssl, conan

I'm trying to build Qt 5.15.2 by Conan without OpenSSL. I haven't succeeded so far to suppress that OpenSSL is built with. I tried several combinations of options etc.

The command line is as following:

```
conan install qt/5.15.2@ --build --profile gcc103 -o qt:openssl=False -o openssl=False
```

My conanfile.txt looks like following:

```
[requires]
qt/5.15.2@

[settings]
compiler=gcc
build_type=Release

[generators]
cmake

[options]
*:shared=True
qt:openssl=False
```

Does anybody know to to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: using `./configure` and `make` to build Qt is standard.  If you want help compiling, you may wish to go that route or translate the `conan` output into the equivalent `./configure[...]` command, debug that, and translate it back to `conan`.

Comment: The option `-o qt:openssl=False`should be enough. Otherwise, open an issue to Conan Center Index, where that recipe lives: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/ Don't forget to write with more details, like OS, log output, etc ...